# Sub-gaussian norm of linear combination

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, normal-distribution, orlicz-spaces

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N$ be independent subgaussian random variables, and let $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N$ be nonnegative constants.

Consider the random variable $Y = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i X_i$.

I want to Prove that
$$
\|Y\|_{\psi_2} \leq C(\max_{i=1}^N \|X_i\|_{\psi_2}) \|a\|_2,
$$
for some positive constant $C$.

I suppose I will be using General Hoeffding's inequality

$$
\mathbb{P}(Y \geq t) \leq 2 \exp\left(-\frac{ct^2}{(\max_{i=1}^N \|X_i\|_{\psi_2})^2 \|a\|_2^2}\right),
$$

I tried using Markov's inequality on $\mathbb{P}(Y \geq t)$ such that

$$
\mathbb{P}(Y \geq t) \leq \frac{E(e^{Y^2})}{e^{t^2}}
$$

and then equate this to the right hand side of General Hoeffding's but I'm not sure how to substitute this in subgaussian norm to get the right form or if I'm not going in the right direction.

Comment: Aren't $X_i$'s mean zero? I gave an answer below assuming that they are mean zero.

Comment: Also, $a_i$'s don't need to be nonnegative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use one of the equivalent conditions for sub-gaussian random variables. For any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,

\begin{align*}
E \exp \left(\lambda \sum_{i=1}^N a_i X_i \right)
& = \prod_{i=1}^N E \exp (\lambda a_i X_i) \\
& \leq \prod_{i=1}^N \exp (C\lambda^2 a_i^2 \|X_i \|_{\psi_2}^2) \\
& = \exp \left( C \lambda^2 \sum_{i=1}^N a_i^2\|X_i \|_{\psi_2}^2 \right)
\end{align*}

The first equality is because of the independence and the inequality is due to one of the equivalent definitions of sub-gaussian random variables.

Finally, note that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N a_i^2\|X_i \|_{\psi_2}^2 \leq \max_i \|X_i\|_{\psi_2}^2 \sum_{i=1}^N a_i^2
$$

Comment: Everything sounds reasonable to me except the first Expectation, I can't get how it was derived I mean $E \exp \left(\lambda \sum_{i=1}^N a_i X_i \right)$

Comment: This is one of the equivalent definitions of sub-gaussian random variables (and the reason why mean zero assumption matters). Take a look at Prop 2.5.2 of Roman Vershynin's High Dimensional Probability. https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf

Comment: I get the equivalent definitions part. what I don't get on the other hand is, can I say that $\|Y\|_{\psi_2} \leq E \exp \left(\lambda \sum_{i=1}^N a_i X_i \right)$

Comment: No, that's not meant here. We have shown $E \exp (\lambda Y) \leq \exp (C\lambda^2 \sum a_i^2 \|X_i\|_{\psi_2}^2)$. Using the equivalent condition again shows $\|Y\|_{\psi_2}\leq c\sqrt{\sum a_i^2 \|X_i\|_{\psi_2}^2}$